How to prevent cursor from jumping to the end in a controlled input in React?
I'm working on a form in React where I have a controlled input field. I'm using a method bindTextField to handle the input's value and events. Here's the code:
  bindTextField = (id: FIELD_TYPE, options?: { autoTrim?: boolean, autoLowerCase?: boolean, formatPhoneNumber?: boolean } & TextFieldHooks) => {
    const { autoTrim, autoLowerCase, formatPhoneNumber, ...hooks } = (options || {});
    const value = this.form.$(id).value;
  
    if (formatPhoneNumber) {
      const formattedPhoneNumber = formatPhoneNumberWithDefaultCountryCode(value);  
      if (formattedPhoneNumber) {
        this.form.$(id).onChange(formattedPhoneNumber);
      }
    }

    return {
      value: this.form.$(id).value,
      label: this.form.$(id).label,
      onBlur: (event: FocusEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>) => {
        const inputValue = event?.target?.value;
        let newValue = inputValue;
        if (autoTrim) {
          newValue = typeof inputValue === 'string' ? newValue.trim() : newValue;
        }
        if (formatPhoneNumber) {
          const phoneNumber = formatPhoneNumberWithDefaultCountryCode(newValue);
          newValue = phoneNumber || newValue;
        }

        if (autoLowerCase) {
          newValue = typeof inputValue === 'string' ? newValue.toLowerCase() : newValue;
        }
        if (newValue !== value) {
          this.form.$(id).onChange(newValue);
        }

        this.form.$(id).onBlur();
        hooks?.onBlur?.(event);
        this.onSave();
      },
      error: !!this.form.$(id).error,
      helperText: this.form.$(id).error,
      onChange: (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>) => {
        this.form.$(id).onChange(event);
        hooks?.onChange?.(event);
      },
      onFocus: this.form.$(id).onFocus,
      inputProps: {
        autoComplete: 'off',
        autoCorrect: 'off',
        autoCapitalize: 'off',
      },
    };
  };


When I type in the input field, the cursor jumps to the end of the input after each keystroke. This happens even when I'm trying to edit the text in the middle of the input.
I've tried several solutions, including using a ref to store the cursor position and restore it after updating the state, but none of them have worked so far.
However, this code still results in the cursor jumping to the end of the input.
